# Extract column names from sqlalchemy TextClause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a sqlalchemy TextClause, such as:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text
tc = text("SELECT * FROM some_table")
```

is it possible to extract the column names from the TextClause object `tc`?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, unless you have already associated it with a `columns` object.

Comment: thanks, I figured a work around, but it only works in certain contexts (i.e. MSSQL, must start with SELECT, not CTE (i.e. WITH): 
`pd.read_sql("select top 0 * from (" + tc + ") as anon_top_zero", con).columns`